Midrashim that explore the exact meaning of "tov" in Genesis 1?
It's no secret that "good," in English as well as in Hebrew, is rather polysemous: on the one hand, it can mark the degree to which a given thing satisfies its purpose or relevant ideal (as in a "good table," "good car," etc: in each case, the specifications of "good" are relative to the noun that follows it); on the other, it can identify moral righteousness — good in the unqualified, ethical sense.
As such, I'm wondering about the history of the interpretation of the word "good" ("tov") as it appears in Creation, specifically in Genesis 1. My question isn't what the word means, but rather when and how Jewish readers attempted to establish its meaning, using either the exegetical tools of midrash or those of philosophy. That is: when and where, exactly, do we see an attempt to define the Creational "tov" in  biblical commentary?
Unsurprisingly, I've found relevant passages in Midrash Lekach Tov, but I'm wondering if this is really the starting point for my search. Is there anything earlier, or indeed, anything else at all? It would seem to be a question with major conceptual stakes, at least for the modern reader...

Welcome to the Mi Yodeya community. Thank you for your first question. We look forward to learning with you.

What do you mean by "exact meaning"? The beauty of the scripture is in its opaqueness, vagueness, the possibility of multiple interpretations, a base for fruitful and creative arguments, and more. There are hundreds of interpretations on "וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים אֶת־הָאוֹר כִּי־טוֹב" https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.1.4?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en

I would have preferred this to be a comment rather than an answer, but so far, I lack those privileges.
A great source for the discussion of what is tov can be found in the Maharal's commentary to Avot 1:2. On Sefaria

This is excellent and quite fascinating, thanks. It does strike me that it's rather late, though -- 16th century and all. Do you happen to know of any earlier discussions that Maharal might be drawing upon?

Beyond the Rashi that he cites, that is
